# iPhone create/register/add new custom smiley keyboard

Tags: iphone, iphone-softkeyboard

i need a custom keyboard like Emoji application does in my application. Any ideas how to create/register/add a new custom smiley keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're targeting for AppStore — you can't create/register/add a custom keyboard that reuses Apple's code (as they're undocumented). The only way you can do is **create a custom view** with many buttons as the keys.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kenny, but how do i encode an smiley image as string and other iphone decodes it? or should i be using webviews ?

Comment: @Ubersoldat: You can use Emoji, which corresponds to unicode in range U+e0xx to U+e5xx. See http://pukupi.com/post/1964/. Emoji doesn't need a web view.

Comment: i know emoji can do that, but how can i implement this in my application?

Comment: @Ubersoldat: Which kind of implementation?

Comment: that encoding decoding stuff?

Comment: @Ubersoldat: Just put a `@"\uE012"` to the text view and the iPhoneOS will translate that into Emoji automatically.

Comment: ohh that worked, thanks Kenny :)
and one more question: how do i make the magnifying affect for these smiley buttons like keyboard?

Comment: @Ubersoldat: You could try to make a view dis/appear in response to `UIButton`'s touchDown or touchUpInside events.